# Android stock camera app source, why is there no AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, camera

I wanted to look at the source of the stock Android camera app to figure out how to handle some intermittent errors I'm seeing in my own app. I have imported the [Git repo](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera) for the latest version, but the AndroidManifest.xml seems to be missing.

Looked at the LegacyCamera repo and it also doesn't have a manifest. Same is true for the [Cyanogen Mod camera app](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Camera).

Being able to build the app would be quite helpful, but reconstructing the manifest by hand doesn't sound like fun.

Am I looking in the wrong place, or is there a reason for this? Surely it's not an oversight if neither of the three repos has one. Feeling pretty stupid right now.

Comment: why not simply pull the Camera.apk from your device, and decompile it with apktools? http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/. You should be able to extract the Manifest with this method.

Comment: Good call, thanks. Hadn't crossed my mind. Still wondering whether there's a reason for the omission though.

Comment: Mystery solved. I was looking for the Camera.apk on my phone (Galaxy Nexus, 4.1.1) and couldn't find it anywhere. Checked the app info on the Camera launcher icon and the app name was displayed as 'Gallery'. Turns out Camera is integrated into Gallery now, so that's also why the Camera doesn't have its own manifest. If someone else has the same problem, look at /platform/packages/apps/Gallery2. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.